# Identical queries in Mongoose and RoboMongo to the same database produce different results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some flight data in a mongodb and I'm trying to bring back each of the airline names and airline codes. There can be multiple records with the same airline name, so I just want it to come back once.

When I run the following query in RoboMongo(Robo3T) I correctly get back what I'm after.

```
db.getCollection('data').aggregate([
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "airlineName": "$airlineName",
                    "airlineCode": "$airlineCode"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

The above returns records with both the airlineName and airlineCode grouped under _id.

When I run the following code in node/express. Only airlineCode is returned.

```
Airline.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "airlineName": "$airlineName",
                "airlineCode": "$airlineCode"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble here, but there is literally no difference when using mongoose at all. So the only way you get different results is that in fact you're likely looking at different data sources. Noting `getCollection('data')` is not what an `Airline = mongoose.model('Airline', new Schema({}))` is actually looking for by name of the collection. Mongoose is looking in the `airlines` collection of whatever database you are actually connecting to.

Comment: Which basically translates to your data in the "completely different collection" has no property named `airlineName`, and as such nothing is returned. You probably typed the case differently into your mongoose schema. But still, "completely different collections" sorry.

Comment: Hi. Please dont apologise. I was thinking the same thing at first "how can it possibly return different results, it must be the data source!" but then after what i thought was a thorough check (obviously not thorough enough haha) I thought they were identical sources. Anyway after reading what you said I've noticed it straight away.

I had 2 very similarly named datasources which confused me. I've now fixed the issue so thanks very much. Lesson learned, dont make the collections too similar!

Comment: Dude they are not identical. Pay attention because that is what I am even showing you by example. Two completely different collections.

Comment: Sorry I pressed add comment before i finished typing. (thought pressing return would create a new line but it posted)